# Is the Ideal World a possible world?

Tags: possible-worlds

Is there any sense in postulating that there is a way to reach a so called "Ideal World"? By Ideal World I mean, in a sense, the best of all possible worlds.

Comment: And by best you mean...?

Comment: That this can be done is certain. It would depend on (i) your definition of the set of properties an ideal world should satisfy, and (ii) the definition of accessibility relation (the "way of reaching" worlds). Whether there is any point to it, I can't tell. Depends on personal opinion. So I'm voting to close this.

Comment: If you can define "reach" in some way that makes this non-opinion based, I will reconsider.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  In certain modal logics, the concepts of necessity and possibility are taken as quantifications over those worlds that are *accessible* to a world, which allows us to say things like "necessarily, P, but *not necessarily* necessarily P".

If we have a semantics in which there is a value assigned to a given world (let's say the number of cute fuzzy bunnies in that world), we can talk about the value of that measure in all of the accessible worlds (all of the possible ways things might be only have so many cute fuzzy bunnies).  The choice function that says we can pick out an accessible world that maximises that value (we want "a world with the greatest number of fuzzy bunnies") follows from the semantics.

Now what this line doesn't give you is an *algorithm* - it is just an existence property, rather than a generative procedure, as is common with most choice functions.  To make this more palatable, you would need a more precise account of why some worlds are accessible and others are not.  For instance, just what is it in virtue of which a certain number of fuzzy bunnies might exist?  Arguably that's a matter of the science of the measured value, rather than pure philosophy. In my case ecology, presumably.

For a more careful and considered notion of what it would mean to create a more Just world, say, you would really need to look at empirical political and social science, and what they tell you about how positive change can be brought about.  (but more fuzzy bunnies would be a good start)